# How to solve this system of equations with five unknowns?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I want to know if there are exact solutions to the following system of five equations with five unknowns $A,B,D,F,R$ , with a step by step solution

$AD=32$

$AF+BD=16$

$AR+BR+D=-32$

$BR+F+A=-12$

$R+B=6$

Comment: Are there any limitations on the values the five variables are allowed to take on?  Are there any approaches you have already tried?

Comment: I'm triying to factor the solvable quintic equation  $ 32x^5+16x^4-32x^3-12x^2+6x+1 $ as a product of two quadratic and cubic factors of the form $ (Ax^2 + Bx + 1)(Dx^3 + Fx^2 + Rx + 1) $. Then, by expanding these factors and equating coefficients, I get this system. Is there a solution for these variables?

Comment: There is of course a real solution, but the polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I know that, but can the variables A, B, D, F, R, be expressed by radicals?